# Why checking "Run as administrator" fails is it a bug of Vista or of the software?

Tags: windows-vista

I have followed this http://www.lancelhoff.com/how-to-run-a-program-in-vista-with-administrator-rights/

to run a program in compatibility mode and as administrator but it doesn't work.

Is it because it's a bug of Vista or of the software ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because it's a bug of Vista or of the software ?

More like an in-compatibility between the software and Vista. It would be harsh to describe this as a bug without knowing more details.

Not all programs will work in 'Compatibility mode' which is Microsoft they introduced [Virtual XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) which has a even better chance of running older programs. But even then there is no guarantee that an older program will run.